# phpMyAdmin 4 configuration for multiple users (Ubuntu 14.04, Apache2, PHP5)

Tags: apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I am asking for the configuration for phpMyAdmin so that multiple users can access their own databases with full rights but cannot see, edit or remove other databases.

I installed phpMyAdmin like this:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin

Web server to reconfigure automatically: <-- apache2
Configure database for phpmyadmin with dbconfig-common? <-- No
```

The installtion is running successfully but I only can access phpMyAdmin as root.
If I create a database 'testdb' and grant priviliges like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON testdb.* TO 'user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass1';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I am still not able to access phpMyAdmin with the user1 credentials. Why?
How do I give user1 all priviliges on his database with access to phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works to give access to multiple users:

First of all update your phpmyadmin version for Ubuntu:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/source.list

## Untrusted PPA phpMyAdmin
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nijel/phpmyadmin/ubuntu trusty main

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

After installing the latest version configure phpmyadmin:

```
mysql > CREATE DATABASE phpmyadmin;

Import into phpmyadmin database „create_tables.sql.gz“
from the directory „/usr/share/doc/phpmyadmin/examples“

Add new user pma to database phpmyadmin:
CREATE USER 'pma'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pmapassword';

GRANT USAGE ON mysql.* TO 'pma'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'pmapassword';

GRANT SELECT (Host, User, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv,
    Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv, File_priv,
    Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv, Show_db_priv, Super_priv,
    Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv, Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv,
    Repl_client_priv) ON mysql.user TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.db TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.host TO 'pma'@'localhost';
GRANT SELECT (Host, Db, User, Table_name, Table_priv, Column_priv) ON
    mysql.tables_priv TO 'pma'@'localhost';

GRANT SELECT (Host, User, Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv,
    Create_priv, Drop_priv, Reload_priv, Shutdown_priv, Process_priv, File_priv, 
    Grant_priv, References_priv, Index_priv, Alter_priv, Show_db_priv, Super_priv,
    Create_tmp_table_priv, Lock_tables_priv, Execute_priv, Repl_slave_priv,
    Repl_client_priv) ON mysql.user TO 'pma'@'localhost';

GRANT SELECT ON mysql.db TO 'pma'@'localhost';

GRANT SELECT ON mysql.host TO 'pma'@'localhost';

GRANT SELECT (Host, Db, User, Table_name, Table_priv, Column_priv) ON
    mysql.tables_priv TO 'pma'@'localhost';


sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/ config-db.php

$dbuser='pma';
$dbpass=‘pmapassword‘;
$basepath='';
$dbname='phpmyadmin';
$dbserver='127.0.0.1';
$dbport='3306';
$dbtype='mysql';


sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = $dbuser;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = $dbpass;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '^(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|phpmyadmin)$';
```